# API access through VNet integration is blocked (but working in Kudu console)

Tags: azure-web-app-service, vnet

I have configured two App Services (following [this tutorial](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2022/12/02/n-tier-web-app.html)):

1. Frontend app - all outbound traffic is using a subnet (`10.0.0.0/24`) on a VNet
2. Backend app - access restrictions are set to 'block public access' and I assigned a Private Endpoint connection using a second subnet (`10.0.1.0/24`) on the same virtual network as the frontend.

After this configuration, the 'inbound address' on the backend changed to an IP address within the virtual network (`10.0.1.x`) instead of a public IP address. Visiting the backend with the URL shows the 403 FORBIDDEN error as I expected.

In the Kudu console I see that the `WEBSITE_PRIVATE_IP` has an internal IP address within the VNet (`10.0.0.x`). Executing the following commands in the Kudu Bash shell shows that all configuration looks fine:

`nslookup [backend-app].azurewebsites.net` returns `Address: 10.0.1.x`

`curl https://[backend-app].azurewebsites.net` returns the contents of the backend site.

When I run these commands from another terminal session, `nslookup` returns the external IP address, and the `curl` command returns `403 FORBIDDEN`.

So far, so good.

However, when the frontend app makes a request to the backend (using Axios package), it still receives a `403 IP FORBIDDEN` error. How comes that the Kudu console can make the request, but the frontend app itself is not allowed to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing sticking out to me, based on the information you've provided, is verifying the front-end is calling the correct backend host. Assuming you've already verified that and [Route All is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-vnet-integration-routing#configure-application-routing), then I would reference [Troubleshoot virtual network integration with Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-vnet-integration-apps), specifically, [Network troubleshooter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-vnet-integration-apps#network-troubleshooter) so you can collect some traces.

As weird as it may, sounds like your front-end code ignoring Azure Private DNS and the traffic is routing out into the internet rather than going through the VNET.